# How to set styles for different headlines (h1, h2, ...) in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would like to have two different styles for the h1, h2, h3 etc.

I tried using classes for the styles like this:

```
.version-one{
h1{
    ...
}
h2{
    ...
}
}
```

And then in the html:

```
<h1 class="version-one">Title</h1>
```

But this did not work. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Whatever the best answer is in your opinion should be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 6):

You're not correclty using css selectors.

To select the h1 on your page which has a class `version-one` (or respectively version-two), just type this:

**HTML:**

```
<h1 class="version-one">red headine</h1>
<h1 class="version-two">blue heading</h1>
```

**CSS:**

```
.version-one {
    /* your styles for the class version-one */
    font-size: 3em;
    color: red;
}

.version-two {
    /* your styles for the class version-two */
    font-size: 3em;
    color: blue;
}
```

You also could use `h1.version-one` as the selector to ensure you're only targetting h1-elements with this class and not other elements with this class (e.g. a paragraph).

Answer (score 1):

Use it the other way around, so:

CSS

```
.version-one h1 {
    color: red;
}
.version-one h2 {
    color: orange;
}

.version-two h1 {
    color: blue;
}
.version-two h2 {
    color: purple;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="version-one">
    <h1>lorem lipsum</h1>
    <h2>lorem lipsum</h2>
</div>

<div class="version-two">
    <h1>lorem lipsum</h1>
    <h2>lorem lipsum</h2>
</div>
```

This works.

[The jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LDNjg/)

Comment: wow a downvote in less then 20 seconds? Im interested why that would be?

Comment: @kleinfreund how about now?

Comment: The jsFiddle works, because you add the **generated** css there, the syntax you wrote, is something like **LESS** and need compile before browser can understand it. Btw, i'm not the cause of downvote `;)`. **+1** for editing it.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a class on the container element and set styles through it

```
.varient1 h1 { color: Red; }
.varient1 h2 { color: Green; }

.varient2 h1 { color: Blue; }
.varient2 h2 { color: Yellow; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your markup:

```
<h1 class="version1">Version 1</h1>
<h1 class="version2">Version 2</h1>
<h1 class="version3">Version 3</h1>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.version1 { background: red; }
.version2 { background: blue; }
.version3 { background: green; }
```